# How to decode JSON value that can be either string or int

Tags: swift

Essentially I have the following JSON response I am decoding using the the following struct. What can be added to struct to make it work with a value that can either come through as a String or Int?

**JSON Response:**

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 122312,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
```

**Struct:**

```
struct TestStruct: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let code: ??
    let notes: String
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will require a custom decoding implementation.

If the property can truly be either a number or a string, the easiest way is to use an enum type.

Additionally, if you want to decode a date object you'll need to pass in a date decoding strategy to your decoder.

Throw this in a playground:

```swift
let data = """
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 122312,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

enum Code: Decodable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    var date: Date
    var code: Code
    var notes: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, code, notes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        self.notes = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)

        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = .int(value)
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = .string(value)
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unable to decode value for `code`")
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Code.self, context)
        }
    }
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

let items = try! decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data)

for item in items {
    print("date: \(item.date.description)")
    print("code: \(item.code)")
    print("notes: \(item.notes)")
    print()
}
```

Comment: Anyway to not prefix the int and string in the final responses of code?

Comment: I’m not too sure what you mean by prefix? If you mean the enum cases, then no, each case must have some kind of name. Otherwise, I’m not sure what you’re referring to.

Comment: Understood. Why are the leading 0’s being cut from the integer? For example if I have a 0038483 in the json it will interpret it as 38483.

Comment: Because the type is Int. Leading zeros will only remain if you treat the data as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming however the data received, the `TestStruct` will have `String` type for `code` attribute the following snippet should decode it.

```swift
struct TestStruct: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let code: String?
    let notes: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, code, notes
    }

    // custom decoding
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        self.notes = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)
        
        if let strCode = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = strCode
        } else if let intCode = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = String(intCode)
        } else {
            self.code = nil
        }
    }
}
```